# Hive external table on top of parquet data returns null

Tags: database, apache-spark, struct, hive, parquet

I have the below data stored in HDFS in the parquet format. I need to create a HIVE external table on top of it.

```
root
 |-- ABC: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- SID: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- SNAME: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- TEXT: string (nullable = true)
 |-- ABC: long (nullable = true)
 |-- DEF: string (nullable = true)
```

```
create external table if not exists test_data
(
abc struct<sid:string,sname:string,text:string>,
abc bigint,
def string,
)
STORED AS parquet 
LOCATION '/datalake/data.parquet';
```

I tried by giving different names to **abc struct & abc bigint**. In that scenario, I am getting null values. If I give the same column name to **abc struct & abc bigint**, getting an error. Kindly help me to resolve the issue.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot have columns of same name, even if they have different datatypes, as per standard ANSI SQL Syntax.

One approach to this, is reading the parquet files and rewriting the files with renaming one of the duplicate columns.

From there on, its simply pointing the hive table to the created location. You can think of automating the process as well, once desired results are achieved.